# How to fix UITextView text content position in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have `UIView` class and in this class have `UITextView` for use as inputText

In `textViewDidChange` from row 2 through 5 with any inter, or adding text, I add the `UITextView` `bounds.size.height` as much as need.

The problem is, in rows 3 and 5, first line text does not appear.
To be roughly a row above its own space.
And is created from the bottom of the empty space, without scrolling.

[image]

But the text in the 4th row have exact position

```
class QuestionCell: UIView, UITextViewDelegate{

    var paragraph = UITextView()

    func setParagraph(){
        let frame = CGRect(x: 50,
                           y: 0,
                           width: forground.width-55,
                           height: forground.height)
        paragraph.frame = frame
        paragraph.isEditable = true
        paragraph.delegate = self
        // forground is some UIView in this View
        forground.addSubview(paragraph)
    }
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
       paragraph.bounds.size.height = paragraph.paragraphHeight
    }
}

extension UITextView{
    var paragraphHeight: CGFloat{
        let fixedWidth = self.width
        let newSize = self.sizeThatFits(CGSize.init(width: fixedWidth,
                                                         height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
        var newFrame = self.frame
        newFrame.size = CGSize.init(width: CGFloat(fmaxf(Float(newSize.width),
                                                         Float(fixedWidth))),
                                    height: newSize.height)
        return newSize.height
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps show us the code?

Comment: How have you been calculating the size of the textView? Maybe it is rounding up your number of rows. I mean when it is an odd number.

Comment: I am using extension UITextView for calculating the size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During Creating you need to specify :

```
  paragraph.isScrollEnabled = false
```

After creating, you may set it back.